What is the best way to include a development dependency into the nuget package without referencing it in the actual project
In advance: although I have not tried it out yet, as far as I know, a workaround for my problem is adding a full .nuspec file to the project and setting some extra properties in .csproj for msbuild.
I have an API project that included analyzers related to the API's usage, but I had to separate them. The analyzer still references the API project and uses types from the latter. Hence I can't add a project reference from the API to the analyzer, as it would result in a cyclic reference indifferent from the asset control. Neither can I add the analyzer to the API project as a package reference as it is not the one that should be analyzed. Those to be analyzed are the clients consuming the API. I want to add the analyzer package as a development dependency, but only for them.
I already have such a thing for other reasons:
<Target Name="SetNuSpecProperties" BeforeTargets="GenerateNuspec">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <NuspecProperties>$(NuspecProperties);Version=$(Version);...;</NuspecProperties>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>

But these are all flat properties. The dependencies is a list. On top of that, it will contain autogenerated dependencies.
Is there a way to inject a dependency in that list from within the .csproj?

Have you looked at the documentation for PackageReference, specifically "Controlling dependency assets"?

As I wrote: "no matter the asset control". That's what I meant. The builder will cry because of the cyclic reference even when those controls do not allow anything to be actually referenced.

I'm not following. If your client project has a PackageReference to the API package and a PackageReference to the analyzer package (which also depends on the API package) there is no circular dependency.

That's not the issue. I can add it manually during development. But I want the nuget package made from the API project to automatically add the analyzer project as well as a development dependency to the client project. The emphasis is on automatically.

See Analyzer NuGet formats in the documentation. To avoid the circular reference, create a new utility project. You might use <Project Sdk="Microsoft.Build.NoTargets"> as the SDK type. This utility project would depend on the API project and the Analyzer project and its purpose would be to create the NuGet package from the other two projects. Essentially you are moving the package creation to its own project. This keeps the build order clean.

Oh. Interesting! I will definitely give it a try. Thank you.


1. Abstract
We've tried this with the approach below and failed. However whilst the solution presented does add dependencies; we haven't been able to implement an end-to-end solution which is likely to be the basis of a production workflow.
If you did continue down this path and got something working, you would most likely end up with something brittle, costly to maintain, and a general headache; all in the name of engineering perfection of autoresolution of dynamically added dependencies. The MsBuild pipeline for both dependency resolution and NuGet package building is incredibly inflexible and resists change. It's my appraisal that it's not up to the task.
2. How Visual Studio Nuget dependency resolution works
There's actually two ways that dependencies get dependencies in a Visual Studio Project.
2.1. Build Dependencies
When executing a dotnet build, msbuild /t: build, and "Build" are selected in the IDE. In this case, $(PackageReference) is read in order to add the dependencies to the Nuspec. This needs to be executed after ResolvePackageAssets, and executed by one of the asset resolution pipelines, such as ResolvePackageDependenciesForBuildDependsOn.
2.2. Pack Dependency Resolution
When executing dotnet pack, msbuild /t: pack, and selecting "Pack" from the context menu in the IDE. These mechanisms call the Build target then Pack. However when the Build target is called, it's in a special "mode"; without all the full compilation build environment. In this scenario, GenerateNuspec reads the project.assets.json directly when it calls PackTask to build the .nuspec.
3. Approach
Because of the challenges outlined in 2.1 and 2.2, two different methods of dependency injection have to occur. What's more they have to occur a) before resolution of the dependencies and, b) after the environment is in a state to read the command line parameters.
3.1 Injecting dependencies into the build pipeline
So in order to get the build phase to work, we'd need to "hijack" the MsBuild dependency resolution to put our dependencies in there. This would involve inserting a target into the ResolvePackageDependenciesForBuild pipeline or similar:
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ResolvePackageDependenciesForBuildDependsOn>
            GatherPackageReferences;
            $(ResolvePackageDependenciesForBuildDependsOn) 
        </ResolvePackageDependenciesForBuildDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>


Then a target may be implemented to dynamically write to the
PackageDependencies ItemGroup:
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="GatherPackageReferences" Outputs="@(PackageReference);" 
            AfterTargets="ResolvePackageAssets" DependsOnTargets="PackageAssets">
        <PropertyGroup>

        <ItemGroup>
            <PackageReference Include="@(AdditionalPackages)" />
        </ItemGroup>

        <Message Text="Additional packages: @(AdditionalPackages)" Importance="High" />
    </Target>

Performing this target does work, albeit only for builds. There's also the additional caveat about where to get the additional packages. See section 3.3.
3.2 Injecting dependencies into the restore/pack pipeline
So as outlined in 1.2, to get additional dependencies into the pack phase, you need to "hijack" something after the restore phase. After this point the dependencies are written to disk and remain static until the PackTask reads them. No amount of changing in-built Visual Studio variables will change this, it simply doesn't use the Visual Studio environment to perform the packing.
    <Target Name="InjectProjectAssetsDependencies" AfterTargets="Restore">
        <UpdateJsonFrameworks PackageProject="$(PackageProject)" />
    </Target>

The following task as an example, will "steal" the dependencies from another project and inject them into the JSON. Of course now we're in the predicament that we can't use System.Text.Json because it itself is a dependency package. Using a package within this step causes some non-reproducable exceptions within the build in the internal MsBuild targets.
    <UsingTask TaskName="UpdateJsonFrameworks" TaskFactory="RoslynCodeTaskFactory"
               AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll">
        <ParameterGroup>
            <PackageProject ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
        </ParameterGroup>
        <Task>
            <Using Namespace="System.IO" />
            <Using Namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" />
            <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
                <![CDATA[
                const string PackageReferencesPattern = @"(?<=""frameworks""\:.*""frameworks"": \{)([\s\S]*?)(?=\n\s{4}\})";
                const string AssetsFileName = "project.assets.json";
                
                var sourceJsonPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(PackageProject), "obj", AssetsFileName);
                if (!File.Exists(sourceJsonPath))
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Source project's projects.assets.json was not found at '{sourceJsonPath}'.");
                }

                var targetJsonPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "obj", AssetsFileName);
                if (!File.Exists(targetJsonPath))
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Target project's projects.assets.json was not found at '{targetJsonPath }'.");
                }

                var sourceJson = File.ReadAllText(sourceJsonPath);
                var sourcePackageReferencesSection = Regex.Match(sourceJson, PackageReferencesPattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
                if (!sourcePackageReferencesSection.Success)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Could not find the package references section in the source project's projects.assets.json.");
                }

                var targetJson = File.ReadAllText(targetJsonPath );
                var targetPackageReferencesSection = Regex.Match(targetJson, PackageReferencesPattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
                if (!targetPackageReferencesSection.Success)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Could not find the package references section in the target project's projects.assets.json.");
                }

                var modifiedTargetJson = targetJson.Replace(targetPackageReferencesSection.Value, sourcePackageReferencesSection.Value);
                File.WriteAllText(targetJsonPath, modifiedTargetJson);
                Console.WriteLine($"  Injected package references section:");
                Console.WriteLine($"    from: {sourceJsonPath}.");
                Console.WriteLine($"    to: {targetJsonPath }.");
                Console.WriteLine($"    section: {sourcePackageReferencesSection.Value}");
                ]]>
            </Code>
        </Task>
    </UsingTask>

3.3 Gathering additional packages from the command line
To address the original question, we want to gather provided additional packages from the command line. Now a command line parameter can be specified to a build like this:
   msbuild -p:AdditionalPackage="My.Additional.Package"

This will write the property group item in MsBuild to this value. This will work, but the question constraints set multiple packages. It's not actually possible to specify comma or semicolon delimited parameters. However you can get round this by using a pipe:
   msbuild -p:AdditionalPackages="My.Additional.Package1|My.Additional.Package2"

Then within the target we made for injecting, we can do this:
        <PropertyGroup>
            <SemicolonDelimitedAdditionalPackages>$([System.String]::Copy($(AdditionalPackages)).Replace('|', ';'))</SemicolonDelimitedAdditionalPackages>
        </PropertyGroup>

        <ItemGroup>
            <AdditionalPackagesList Include="$(SemicolonDelimitedAdditionalPackages)" />
        </ItemGroup>

        <ItemGroup>
            <PackageReference Include="@(AdditionalPackagesList)" />
    </ItemGroup>

But note that if you try to do this before dependency resolution occurs, something "funky" happens and the command line property doesn't "take" in the packages list. The command line parsing works, setting the PackageReference to add a new property works - but *it will not work if you set a PackageReference from the command line.
Without a massive teardown of MsBuild my personal interpretation is that the build environment hasn't completed all the prerequisite steps at the point of dependency resolution.
4. Conclusion
Don't do this unless you're approaching it as a purely academic task:

The rigidity of the implementation of Nuget packaging in MsBuild resists change to the degree that any solution will be exceptionally complex and likely brittle.
The complexity required of any such solution would not only have a significant maintainance overhead, but would be complex to the degree that it would require a key-skill expert to maintain the solution.
Due to the required replication of logic of the MsBuild packing and dependency resolution to get this to work, it would lay any solution open to lack of future-proofing; a new MsBuild version could violate the assumptions required and cause the solution to break.

As alternatives, possibly consider manual maintenance of packages, with the ease of maintenance that Central Package Management (CPM) provides.
